# Is there any way to enable Log Analytics on Logic app once it is created?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-log-analytics

```
I want to know is there any way to enable Log Analytics on Logic app once it is already created?
```

I can able to `see option is there while creating a new logic app` but what if logic app is already created , `How to enable Log Analytics on those logic apps?`

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Navigate to your logic app in the azure portal -> `Diagnostic settings` -> `Add diagnostic setting` -> select the `Send to Log Analytics` and LOG or Metric -> `Save`.

[image]